# How to change page layout with my application

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I created an application which has a layout in its package, I want to apply the layout for contact page
I know we can change with layout assignment in Customize, But how can i assign layout to profile with my application

Comment: Define "application". The Admin typically assigns the layouts even if it is a managed package.

Comment: I created an App, I want to change default layout of contact page when user install my app through appexchange

Answer (score 1):

Here is the applicable information regarding page layout from the documentation:

> Page Layouts
>
> - The page layout of the person uploading a package is the layout used    for Group and Professional Edition organizations and becomes
>     the    default page layout for Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, and
>     Developer Edition organizations.
> - Page layouts should be packaged alongside complimentary record types    if the layout is being installed on an existing object.
>     Otherwise,    the installed page layouts must be manually applied to
>     profiles.
> - If a page layout and a record type are created as a result of    installing a package, then the uploading user’s page layout
>     assignment for that record type is assigned to that record type for
>     all profiles in the subscriber organization unless a profile is
>     mapped during an install or upgrade.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_behavior.htm

Possible Duplicate Question:

[Update layout in post install script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12016/update-layout-in-post-install-script)

Comment: I try to install app with page layout Contact (which is already exists), but it is not replacing the existing layouts..., and my app is not installed, if i use cloned layout with unique name, then also it shows duplicate files (For New Case, Log a Call) But these all are comes with the cloned layout... Now i want add a section in Contact Detail page layout who installs my app

Comment: The name "LogACall" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

2.  Duplicate Name
The name "NewNote" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

3.  Duplicate Name
The name "NewTask" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

4.  Duplicate Name
The name "NewCase" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

5.  Duplicate Name
The name "NewEvent" is already used on component type: Action. Please rename existing component.

Comment: I don't understand how can i set my layout as default for contact page, When my application installs it shows in layout list, but user need to be manually set the layout by edit layout assignments, i want it(Setting default layout) to be automatic

Answer (score 0):

I Installed my app with my layout after removing all these elements as i did not needed them. If you also do not need it, You can remove these and upload your app.

Hope this helps you. 
Best Of Luck ! Cheers